# Does ATMega 328/2560 chips support JTAG-type programmer and hardware debugger?

Tags: arduino-uno, avrdude, debugging, avr-gcc

As stated in [www.Arduino.cc FAQ](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ), "Can I use an Arduino board without the Arduino software? Sure. It's just an AVR development board, you can use straight AVR C or C++ (with avr-gcc and avrdude or AVR Studio) to program it."

For UNO/Pro Mini(ATMega328) and ATmega2560, does these two chips support JTAG type (some chip manufacturers may use different name) programmer / hardware-based debugger in same manner as the ST-Link/J-Link programmer/debugger where one can **load code** into the MCU and perform **hardware break point** and single stepping? Example as in  [STM32 development board with ST-LINK programmer / debugger](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF252419?sc=internet/evalboard/product/252419.jsp) where the chip has built-in debug circuit that communicate with ST-Link.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ATmegaXX8 does not support JTAG, but the ATmegaXX0, 'XX1, and 'XX4 do. The 'XX8 (as well as other AVR families) supports debugWIRE, which allows debugging over ISP. You will need one of Atmel's debuggers such as the AVR ONE! or the Atmel-ICE as well as Atmel Studio in order to use it.

Comment: I use an AVRDragon board with Atmel Studio to do JTAG on a 2560 board and DebugWire on the smaller chips. This is probably the lowest cost solution.

Comment: Is the Mega 2560 included in the "ATmegaXX0" class?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: Yes. It includes the ATmega640, ATmega1280 (Arduino Mega), and ATmega2560 (Arduino Mega 2560), which only vary by amount of flash available.